# Typescript: Field's type in a conditional type while passing an enum with a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, types, enums, conditional-statements

I have a `Type<T>` which is supposed to have a field `additionalField` with a type of `T[]`.
I need to make this field optional, depending on if there's a generic being passed.
So I introduce a `ConditionalType<T = void>`, in which if I don't pass a generic - then there's no `additionalField`.

So I have an enum `MyEnum` and in `ConditionalType<MyEnum>` I expect `additionalField` to be of type `MyEnum[]`. Instead, `additionalField` has a type of `MyEnum.TEST_1[] | MyEnum.TEST_2[]`.

Here's the full code:

```ts
type ConditionalType<T = void> = {
  someField: string;
} & (T extends void ? {} : {
  additionalField: T[];
})

type Type<T> = {
  someField: string;
  additionalField: T[];
}

enum MyEnum  {
  TEST_1 = "test_1",
  TEST_2 = "test_2"
}

const a: ConditionalType<MyEnum>;
a.additionalField
// (property) additionalField: MyEnum.TEST_1[] | MyEnum.TEST_2[]
// Need to make it MyEnum[] somehow

const b: Type<MyEnum>;
b.additionalField;
// (property) additionalField: MyEnum[]
// Works as expected
```

Could someone please tell me, how can I make `additionalField` to be of type `MyEnum[]` instead of `MyEnum.TEST_1[] | MyEnum.TEST_2[]` in `ConditionalType<MyEnum>`? In the original `Type<T>` it works as expected and `additionalField` has the type of `MyEnum[]` in `Type<MyEnum>`;

And if this is supposed to work this way, why is this happening with `ConditionalType<T = void>`?

Here's a link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYBVwQA8uUAvFAG5wpIB8ZUA3gFBRQDOcAthAGIoRsSAFwdgAJxQIA5gG5mAXygAyKAAoSEAB7AIydpWpIoAfiZLRLNpiSp0WbP0EiouANoBdeQoCUzZqCQrgTE9ORWHNx8AkKi7BJScqxQNnYYCDhOsa6e3v56AK5cUACyIACiCEVsEbjlAMq4APoAjAwARLrxre0ANMl1jU0ATB1dwCPtiv4AxojxKaLwyGjpOPiQhGWVRWFMyamrDlkubttVXAB0g80tvaUVF9cNzcMe-WycPCeiAOS6Ol+-QU8kwl0O9gyjhiSGYAHo4eowOI4JBxKAfClbEcoT8HjsrjdWp4oAAffFPInDTyzebAKAAI1EGyI512DAiELW0OcojOjyKzyGdwpgqp72SX2ivKg-20wF+inkDPB2MhmRh8gRSJRaIxWLSxxhojZXBpQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally triggered *[distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)* by writing `T extends void`. The union in `T` is distributed over the conditional leading to the union `MyEnum.TEST_1[] | MyEnum.TEST_2[]` instead of `(MyEnum.TEST_1[] | MyEnum.TEST_2)[]`.

Avoid distribution by wrapping `T` and `void` inside tuples.

```
type ConditionalType<T = void> = {
  someField: string;
} & ([T] extends [void] ? {} : {
  additionalField: T[];
})
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYBVwQA8uUAvFAG5wpIB8ZUA3gFBRQDOcAthAGIoRsSAFwdgAJxQIA5gG5mAXygAyKAAoA2rgC6UCAA9gEZOygaqNXQH4mS0SzaYkqdFmz9BIqLg3b5CgEpmZlBIbwJienIHDm4+ASFRdgkpOVYoJxcMBBwPRO9ff2DjAFcuKABZEABRBDK2GNxqgGVcAH0ARgYAIiNkzu6AGnSm1raAJh6+4AnuxWCAY0RkjNF4ZDRsnHxIQirasqimdMzNtzyvDX26rgA6UfaOwcqam-uW9vHtYbZOHgvRAByIyGQHDBTyTC3U6uHLuBJIZgAeiR6jA4jgkHEoACGWcZzhAJeBzuD06vigAB9iW8yeNfItlsAoAAjUQ7IjXQ4MGIwrbwzyiK6vMrvMZPGmiunfdJ-eKCqDAgzAQGKeQs6H42G5BHyFFojFYnF4rLnBGiLlcBlAA)